# HBM2DDL is trying to map entities across databases other than the target database

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a Spring Boot 1.3.8 application that's connecting to a MySQL 8 DB and I'm using MySQL5Dialect (hibernate 4 included in boot 1.x)

The config parameter 'spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto' is set to 'update' and there is only one data source that specifically points to a database.

But the hbm2ddl utility is scanning the schemas other than the target database specified and mapping the entities to tables with same name in the other databases.

I'm unable to share the source or configuration.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the issue seems to be with the database name. its either an issue with the parameter parsing in spring which is splitting the name after '-' or an issue with mysql 8 driver while handling names that contain '-' in them.
With mysql 5 driver we could see that the database names with a '-' get wrapped in between '`'; like `db-name` and was working fine.

Once I renamed the database replacing the '-' with a '_' everything is working fine.